# How to get last property value in JS Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here each time users selects some option, the node object is added and the state, I need the state of a last node object to post

```
var breadCrumb = [{
      breadCrumbN: {
          node: {
            state: "test",
            node: {
              state: "test^test2",
              node: {
                state: "test^test2^test3",
                node: {
                 state: "test^test2^test3^test4" // like to post the last state. the node object will be added for each selection
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking for tree traversal, if you know what that is.

Comment: So, you need to keep traversing deeper till you ran out of `node` property and only left with `state` property?

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution with recursion.

```js
let obj =  {
   node: {
      state: "test",
      node: {
         state: "test^test2",
         node: {
            state: "test^test2^test3",
            node: {
               state: "test^test2^test3^test4"
            }
         }
      }
   }
};

function getLastNodeState(obj) {
   return obj.node ? getLastNodeState(obj.node) : obj.state;
}

console.log(getLastNodeState(obj));
```

Comment: I have the object inside a array, in that case?

Comment: No matter, you need to call this function for every item's `breadCrumbN` property - getLastNodeState(item.breadCrumbN)

Comment: Cool, got it. Thank you!

here:
var x = function chase() {
 var y = {
 name: "test"
}
return y

}

how to add that last value to y object?

Comment: You can from my above code get not `state` property, but the object itself

Comment: The above snippet works great. I appended the end value to a variable. Now that I just want to add that variable to a object which is in the above mentioned structure.

 var x = function chase() { var y = { name: "test" } return y }

Comment: Look. From the above code just return the `obj`. In it access the `state` and get it value to make another one. After it when you already have the last object which is the `obj`, create on it a new property with the result value

Comment: cool, thanks a lot!